# How can I connect to a MySQL database instance via an EC2 instance

Tags: networking, ssh, amazon-web-services

I am trying to connect from my local machine to a MySQL database that is hosted on AWS. The database itself is not publicly accessible (as in, it is configured to refuse outside connections), but is accessible from an EC2 instance, that is itself externally accessible. By which I mean, I can SSH into the EC2 instance, and from within that session, use the MySQL client on the EC2 instance to connect to the database. The MySQL database and the EC2 instance are part of the same AWS Virtual Private Cloud. Others in my organization are accessing the database by creating an SSH tunnel from their local machine to the EC2 instance, and then using MySQL Workbench, which seems to cater for this situation.

I would like to be able to access the database directly, either from a MySQL client locally, or via, say, JDBC. This would seem to involve routing via the EC2 instance (somehow). Is this possible? Apologies if I'm not being entirely clear, I'm towards the limit of my networking skills here - please ask if I can clarify anything. My OS is Linux (NixOS).

Thanks in advance, and also after the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the answer to your question. You need to use an SSH tunnel.

Not sure if the MySQL client has a built-in SSH tunnel feature. If this is not the case, this is how you set it up:

Assume these are your EC2 instance and DB IP addresses:
EC2: 10.10.1.30
DB: 10.20.2.40

1. On your EC2 instance run: `ssh -R 33060:10.20.2.40:3306 10.10.1.30`
2. Make sure `GatewayPorts` is set to `yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` (`GatewayPorts no`)
3. On your local machine, to access your DB, set your MySQL client DB hostname/IP field to your EC2 instance public IP address and port 33060 (`ex: 123.45.67.89:33060`)

Comment: thanks - that works perfectly.

Comment: you are very welcome!